# two-dimensional probability density

Tags: calculus, probability

This is how a probability density of X and Y is defined in my worksheet:

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{192},  & \text{for}\ 0 \le x \le 4, x\le y \le 2x \\
0, & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases}$$

To make sure it is a density I calculated the double integral $$ \int_0^4\int_x^{2x}\frac{x^2}{192} dy\ dx$$

however I had $\frac13$ as a result... does this mean that my worksheet is wrong, since the probability density must equal 1? Or did something go wrong in my integration?

Answer (score 1):

I also get 1/3, both using manual integration and Mathematica. So $f(x,y)$ indeed isn't a valid probability density in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: thanks for checking... now I can point fingers hahaha